# Lattice stability

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, stability, phonons

If one calculates the phonon dispersion function for cubic lattice in 3d or quadratic lattice in 2d, then it is seen that there exist impulses for which the frequency becomes imaginary. So it seems that such lattices are unstable. Is it true? Or is it just an artifact of a harmonic approximation? Are there cubic/quadratic lattices in nature? I believe there are. How are they stabilized? Please help

Comment: did you also consider the next-nearest-neighbor coupling when deriving the phonon modes? that is - the 'diagonal' harmonic potential between the atom at $i,j$ and at $i\pm 1,j\pm 1$? Usually any such instabilities are removed when these are included

Comment: As I remember, it is Polonium that crystallizes in a simple cubic lattice.

Answer (score 1):

When the dispersion is imaginary you would get what is called an evanescant wave (if I remember correctly from my solid state course). The phonon solutions become decaying exponentials:
$$\psi=\exp({iw(k)t-i\vec k\cdot\vec x)}\rightarrow e^{-b(k) t}\exp(-i\vec k\cdot\vec x)$$
With $b$ some real function of $k$. If you excite the boundaries of this material with a frequency in a region with imaginary dispersion, the excitations will quickly die out inside the material. So in that sense waves with that frequency can't excist in this material.